Jolt Transform to filter elements in list from another list
I have a employeeList from which I need to remove members in the teamList. Members in the teamlist can be there in employeeList or may not be there as shown below
{
  "employeelist": [
    "john",
    "aaron",
    "mike"
  ],
  "teamList": [
    "rachel",
    "john"
  ]
}

Final result
{
  "employeelist": [
    "aaron",
    "mike"
  ]
}

I tried filtering by aaron but how to get the remaining in employeeList
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "list2": {
        "*": "[#2].list[]"
      }
    }
  }
]


You can manage to solve the issue by exchanging keys vs. values twice such as
[
  { //exchange array keys vs. values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$1": "@0"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { //the matched ones,which would have arrays on RHS,are removed
    //whenever exchanged again
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "employeelist": { //filter by desired object only
          "$1": "@2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

